# Python if condition always evaluates to false regardless of user input

Tags: python, if-statement, user-input

Following is my code creating an HTTP or FTP connection depending on user input. The if and elif conditions somehow evaluate to FALSE all the time. Entering 1 and 0 both prints 'Sorry, wrong answer'.

```
domain = 'ftp.freebsd.org'
path = '/pub/FreeBSD/'

protocol = input('Connecting to {}. Which Protocol to use? (0-http, 1-ftp): '.format(domain))
print(protocol)
input()

if protocol == 0:
    is_secure = bool(input('Should we use secure connection? (1-yes, 0-no): '))
    factory = HTTPFactory(is_secure)
elif protocol == 1:
    is_secure = False
    factory = FTPFactory(is_secure)
else:
    print('Sorry, wrong answer')
    import sys
    sys.exit(1)

connector = Connector(factory)

try:
    content = connector.read(domain, path)
except URLError as e:
    print('Can not access resource with this method')
else:
    print(connector.parse(content))
```

**Output:**

```
Connecting to ftp.freebsd.org. Which Protocol to use? (0-http, 1-ftp): 0
0

Sorry, wrong answer
$ python abstractfactory.py
Connecting to ftp.freebsd.org. Which Protocol to use? (0-http, 1-ftp): http
http

Sorry, wrong answer
$ python abstractfactory.py
Connecting to ftp.freebsd.org. Which Protocol to use? (0-http, 1-ftp): 1
1

Sorry, wrong answer

$
```

Please advice. What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python input() takes input as Unicode string, you need to explicitly compare input as integer with 0 like,

```
if int(input) == 0:
    # Do something
elif int(input) == 1:
    # Do something
```

Answer (score 3):

Input in Python 3, which it looks like you are using, comes in as a string. You would need to cast it via `int()` (although this needs to be done with caution and exception handling in the event of bad input) in order to compare it to an integer.